# WSO-AM 1.5.0: Change keystore

Tags: axis, keystore, wso2

I have changed the carbon.xml file and axis2.xml to point to my own key-store. But when I start the wso2-am, the log says:

> WARN - ValidationResultPrinter The default keystore (wso2carbon.jks)
>   is currently being used. To maximize security when deploying to a
>   production environment, configure a new keystore with a unique
>   password in the production server profile.

Exmaple from axis2.xml

```
    <KeyStore>
        <Location>/data/wso2/certs/ibridge.jks</Location>
        <Type>JKS</Type>
        <Password>****</Password>
        <KeyPassword>****</KeyPassword>
    </KeyStore>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you point your jks file in the secret-conf.properties file (AM_HOME\repository\conf\security)?

Comment: We did not touched the secret-conf.properties. It is the default as supplied inthe zip file. The file itself contains only commented lines, '#'. Does this mean it uses the 'default' carbon.jks?

Comment: You need to change this file as well, not only the axis2.xml and carbon.xml.

Answer (score 1):

There will be 2 main reasons you to change keystore default password which is "wso2carbon".

- When moving to production environments keystore should be altered
  from the default of 'wso2carbon'.
- When changing the default keystore.

You can learn how to do this by following this [blog post](http://sencs.blogspot.com/2015/03/how-to-change-default-keystores-and.html).

Answer (score 0):

Did you specify wso2carbon as the alias when creating the KeyStore? When the server starts up it'll search for KeyStores having wso2carbon alias, and if it finds any, it'll assume the default keystore is being used. If this is the case try giving a different alias.